# Maximum of the function of multivariable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I need to find the maximum of the function given by  $z=x^3+xy$ in $A=[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

I think I need to use partial derivatives, but I'm not sure exactly how.

Comment: And what have you tried? Some calculus perhaps?

Comment: Did you try to think about Z varies when you change X and or Y ? What did you try up to now ?

Comment: I think it's taking partial derivatives

Comment: Heard of partial derivatives and Hessian matrix? You should be working towards that direction.

Comment: yes, but not exactly how

Answer (score 3):

If $x<1$ or $y<1$ or both $x$ and $y$ are less than 1, then the sum $x^3+xy<2$. So maximum is attained at $(1,1)$ which is 2.

Comment: This would not be a good idea to write down complete solution with out knowing what OP has tried....